# Logback rolling policy daily malfunctioning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have three microservices in Spring Boot, all of them have the same rolling policies.
The first time in the day that I use them it creates a new log file but this happens three times, each time depending on the microservice that needs to log.
For example when I log in into the application it correctly creates a new log file with the informations in it and rename the one from the previous day and change its location.
When i log out, that is an operation from another microservice, it creates another log file with only that information and the previous data from the login has been sent to the log file in the archived directory.
This happens only the first time that I use the microservices, then everything works fine.
These are my configuration files, thank you in advance:

logback-spring.xml (1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %white(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="HistoricLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/historic.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/historicArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ApplicativeLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/applicative.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/applicativeArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

      <logger name="loggerHistoric" level="info" additivity="false">
          <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
      </logger>

      <logger name="loggerApplicative" level="error" additivity="false">
          <appender-ref ref="ApplicativeLog" />
      </logger>

</configuration>
```

logback-spring.xml (2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %white(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="HistoricLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/historic.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/historicArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ApplicativeLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/applicative.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/applicativeArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

    <logger name="loggerHistoricJSON" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="loggerApplicativeJSON" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ApplicativeLog" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="loggerHistoricSingle" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="loggerApplicativeSingle" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ApplicativeLog" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

logback-spring.xml (3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %white(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="HistoricLog"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/historic.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/historicArchived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

    <logger name="loggerHistoric" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="loggerApplicative" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="loggerLogout" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="HistoricLog" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: The files appear to be exactly the same so probably is not a configuration problem in these files. How is logging configured in each microservice? Is there more than one logger active in each microservice?

Comment: @pringi Yes I have more than one logger in each microservice, I declare them in this way:     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("loggerLogout");